# How to make toolbars in Visual Studio 2010 float?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I used to make my toolbars float in Visual Studio 2008, but it can no longer be done with Visual Studio 2010. Read the documentation and found nothing, any idea how to do that? Holding either Ctrl, Alt, Shift wouldn't help.

Comment: me too :'( quite a regression we got here if you ask me.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=511327&wa=wsignin1.0) - That's impossible on VS 2010.

Comment: Thanks, had no choice but to hide the toolbars to save spaces.

Comment: Microsoft Connect Has Been Retired

Answer (score -2):

Right click on **toolbars** --> **customize...** --> on a "**toolbar**" tab select the toolbar that you want to move --> click on the "**Modify Selection**" and select the "**Dock Location**".

Comment: Wouldn't this do the opposite of making them float?